# Getting ValueError at time of applying tensorflow.convert_to_tensor in Tensorflow and Python

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am trying to put two matrices with different shapes in a tensor in the following way:

```
    import tensorflow as tf
    matrix =  [[1, 2,  3,  4,  5],
              [6,  7,  8,  9, 10],
              [11, 12, 13, 14, 15],
              [16, 17, 18, 19, 20],
              [21, 22, 23, 24, 25]]
    matrix2 = [[1, 2, 3],
              [6, 7, 8],
              [11, 12, 13],
              [16, 17, 18],
              [21, 22, 23]]
    test = []
    test.append(matrix)
    test.append(matrix2)
    with tf.Session().as_default():
         c = tf.convert_to_tensor(test)
         print(c.eval())
```

Executing this code generates the following error:

```
    ValueError: Argument must be a dense tensor: got shape [2, 5], but wanted [2, 5, 5]
```

If I convert those matrices to numpy array then numpy array considers each of the matrices' row as list. Is there any other way I can perform my target operation in Tensorflow?

Comment: The error is due to mismatch of dimensions of `matrix` **(5X5)** and `matrix2` **(5X3)**

Answer (score 0):

The error is due to mismatch in dimensions of `matrix`(5x5) and `matrix2`(5x3).

```
import numpy as np

mat2=[[1,2,3],[6,7,8]]
mat1=[[1,2,3,4,5],[3,4,5,6,7]]
test = []
test.append(mat1)
test.append(mat2)
res=np.array(test)
print res
```

> array([[list([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]), list([3, 4, 5, 6, 7])],
>       [list([1, 2, 3]), list([6, 7, 8])]], dtype=object)

Here `res` is a [Jagged array](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jagged_array). In order to create a tensor you need a [Matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_(mathematics)) i.e the basic difference is **Shape of matrix a.k.a Rank of the tensor(Different from Rank in Mathematics) should be rectangular(number of elements at every row are equal)**  [See here](https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/tensors#Rank).

In your case you are trying to create a tensor from a 3-D list of dimension [(5x5),(5x3)] ie. the dimensions of the two 2-D arrays inside the 3-D array don't match.

**Solution** :

Either make `matrix` [5x3] or make `matrix2` [5x5]